# Access sql aggregate with join

Tags: ms-access

I have one table as follows:

```
tableA

+----+------+------+------+
| ID | fldA | fldB | fldC |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |  123 | xx1  |    1 |
|  1 |  124 | xx3  |    5 |
|  2 |  543 | xx5  |    3 |
|  2 |  465 | px3  |    2 |
|  3 |   73 | ox6  |    7 |
|  3 |   55 | ox7  |   24 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

I'd like to reduce this table by selecting only those records that have the highest value in fldC with respect to field ID, so that we end up with:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | fldA | fldB | fldC |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |  124 | xx3  |    5 |
|  2 |  543 | xx5  |    3 |
|  3 |   55 | ox7  |   24 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

I can reduce with:

```
SELECT ID, Max(fldC) AS MaxC
FROM tableA
GROUP BY ID;
```

But I am having problems trying to include fields fldA and fldB. I'm sure the answer lies in an Inner Join and some Aliasing but can't get things to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
 SELECT a.id, fldA, fldC,  fldC
   from tableA a
        join
      (SELECT ID, Max(fldC) AS MaxC 
         FROM tableA 
        GROUP BY ID) b 
       On a.fldc=b.maxC and a.id=b.id;
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. With a minor change(=maxC) to (=b.maxC) all worked flawless. Cheers again. So just to help me understand, we're selecting the whole table 1st, then Inner Joining on the results of the aggregate subquery - but only where both data set ID's match and fine-tuning to a single result by adding to the ID match "AND a.fldC=b.maxC". This results in ONLY the records in the aggregate subquery with the added ASSOCIATED fields from the outer query. Does this seem an on description? If yes then I think I'm starting to understand things better.

Comment: Yes,  I think you've understood exactly how it worked.  You wanted all the records that had the maximum fldC for every single ID. You already had that part of the query but you needed all the fields and not only ID and fldC. The simplest way to go on from there was to select again from the table and returning for every ID only the rows where fldC was equal to the maximum fldC you already found. In SQL tgere are  other ways to accomplish this,  but I doubt they can be  used in  MS Access (I would use a max(fldC) over (partition by id))

Comment: If you don't mind,  I'm going to edit the answer to correct the issue you have found.  I thought it was not necessary, as it was the only field called maxC, but admittedly I couldn't and can't test it by now.